# Extract data between two words Linux script

Tags: linux

I have data in a file as shown below and need to extract the string between `PER*IC` and `~
PER*IC*FBI DEPT*EM*~`

I tried this:
`grep -P -o '(?<=PER*IC).*?(?=~)' inputfile`
but am getting an error message:

> grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

When i tried 
`grep -P -o '(?<=PER).*?(?=~)' inputfile`
it produces the output:
`*IC*FBI DEPT*EM*`

I want to include `PER*IC` as start of string in code and expected result is 
`*FBI DEPT*EM*`

Comment: `grep -P -o '(?<=PER[*]IC).*?(?=~)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `'(?<=PER*IC).*?(?=~)'` the `'*'` is a repetition character that will match *zero or more* `'R'` characters. You need a literal `'*'` which can be done by including it within a character class, e.g. `[*]` making your expression:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=PER[*]IC).*?(?=~)'
```

Which would return:

```
*FBI DEPT*EM*
```

Comment: Thanks David. What is meant by 'R' characters ?     and lets say if i have PER* IC* FBI DEPT * EM* 123*XM* SIRUS~   and if i give input as PER* IC * EM* means then script should return 123.   If i give input as PER* IC* XM* means then script should return SIRUS   do you think we can write all this in single line of code ?

Comment: It only has to do with what is in the regular expression. `R*` for a regular expression means to match *zero-or-more* `'R'` characters. So you must eliminate the special meaning of `'*'` in the regex by making the `'*'` a literal `'*'` and remove its special meaning controlling repetition.

Comment: David, thanks understood, i am quiet familiar with * then. I am confused after you given R characters,  PER*IC means it search for zero or more 'PER' characters right ? Is it different in linux ?

Comment: No no no.. With a regex of `PER*IC`, it means you search for a `'P'` an `'E'` and then zero or more `'R'` an `'I'` and a `'C'`. So `"PEIC"` would match and so would `"PERRRRRRIC"`, but would not match `"PER*IC"` because the `'*'` as the repetition character in the regex would not match the actual `'*'` character in your input. So you have to use `PER[*]IC` as your regex so it is looking for an actual `'*'` as part of the input. You can also *escape* the `'*'` character as `\*` to remove the repetition meaning as well.

Comment: I tried both [] and \ and working perfectly.  I am trying search expansion using same but got struck lets say i have   PER* IC * EDIDEPT *EM * FEEDBACK@1edisource.com * TE*3305551212~ and I want to take email address, so i have given as   grep -P -o '(?<=PER\*IC).*?(?=~)' | grep -P -o '(?<=EM\*).*?(?=[*])'         this one is working perfectly  but when i try to take the TE it is not working and don't know what to give as end character, because 3305551212 after last number '2' there is no symbol to give like ~ or * , if both ~ or * are not here what should i use ?

Comment: I would use `grep -P -o '\w+@\w+[.]\w{3,}'` using extended regex. Where `\w` is a shorthand for word-characters `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Note, valid e-mail addresses can contain other characters like `"-, _, etc.."` which if you need, you add as part of a character class also containing `\w` like `[\w-_]+`, but for your e-mail, looks like normal characters will do.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is search the data based on Element. 
Example:    
NM1* IL*1*JESSI * PINKMAN * XM* SIRUS~

NM1* IL**WALTER * WHITE* XM* PANDORA* EM* ARIZONA~        

grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[*]IL).?(?=~)' 

"This command gives the NM1 segment until ~"

*1*JESSI * PINKMAN * XM * SIRUS

*WALTER * WHITE * XM * PANDORA* EM* ARIZONA

Now again i have to get the data next to XM  that is 

SIRUS

PANDORA

grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[*]IL).?(?=~)' |  grep -P -o '(?<=XM[*]).?(?=


not sure what to give after ?=

Comment: `grep -P -o 'XM\s+\*\s+\w+' | grep -P -o '\w+$'`